Using Python with fonttools to watermark Glyphs in a font file
I am trying to apply a X over particular fonts in my flask script, although I can apply the 'X' (which is the watermark), I can't combine it in the same layer as the Glyph, so it can be opened in any editor and removed. How can I achieve this programmatically, is it even possible with Python and Fonttools?
Here is my script

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory
import os
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont, TTLibError
from fontTools.pens.ttGlyphPen import TTGlyphPen
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging
from matplotlib.path import Path
from fontTools.pens.basePen import BasePen

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads/'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class GlyphPlotter(BasePen):
    """Custom pen for converting glyph outlines to matplotlib paths."""
    def __init__(self, glyphSet, linewidth=1):
        super().__init__(glyphSet)
        self.path = []
        self.x_points = []
        self.y_points = []
    
    def _moveTo(self, p):
        self.path.append((Path.MOVETO, p))
        self.x_points.append(p[0])
        self.y_points.append(p[1])

    def _lineTo(self, p):
        self.path.append((Path.LINETO, p))
        self.x_points.append(p[0])
        self.y_points.append(p[1])

    def _curveToOne(self, p1, p2, p3):
        self.path.append((Path.CURVE4, p1))
        self.path.append((Path.CURVE4, p2))
        self.path.append((Path.CURVE4, p3))
        self.x_points.extend([p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]])
        self.y_points.extend([p1[1], p2[1], p3[1]])

    def _closePath(self):
        self.path.append((Path.CLOSEPOLY, self.path[0][1]))

def add_cross_overlay(glyph, glyph_set, stroke_width):
    """Adds a 'X' sign overlay at the center of the glyph's bounding box with thick lines."""
    plotter = GlyphPlotter(glyph_set)
    glyph.draw(plotter)

    if plotter.x_points and plotter.y_points:
        xMin, xMax = min(plotter.x_points), max(plotter.x_points)
        yMin, yMax = min(plotter.y_points), max(plotter.y_points)
    else:
        xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax = 0, 0, 1000, 1000  # Default bounding box

    centerX = (xMin + xMax) / 2
    centerY = (yMin + yMax) / 2

    logging.debug(f"Drawing X on glyph with bounding box ({xMin}, {yMin}, {xMax}, {yMax})")

    pen = TTGlyphPen(glyph_set)
    glyph.draw(pen) 

    # Draw a thick X by creating a parallelogram path
    pen.moveTo((xMin, yMax))
    pen.lineTo((xMax, yMax - stroke_width))
    pen.lineTo((xMax - stroke_width, yMin))
    pen.lineTo((xMin + stroke_width, yMin))
    pen.closePath()

    pen.moveTo((xMax, yMax))
    pen.lineTo((xMin, yMax - stroke_width))
    pen.lineTo((xMin + stroke_width, yMin))
    pen.lineTo((xMax - stroke_width, yMin))
    pen.closePath()

    new_glyph = pen.glyph()
    return new_glyph

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(filepath)
        try:
            watermark_font(filepath)
        except TTLibError as e:
            logging.error(f"Error processing font: {e}")
            return f"Error processing font: {e}"
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)

def watermark_font(filepath):
    font = TTFont(filepath)
    glyph_set = font.getGlyphSet()

    for char in ['T', 'h', 'e']:
        glyph_name = font.getBestCmap().get(ord(char))
        if glyph_name:
            glyph = glyph_set[glyph_name]

            # Apply a watermark
            new_glyph = add_cross_overlay(glyph, glyph_set, stroke_width=30)

            # Replace the glyph in the font
            font['glyf'][glyph_name] = new_glyph

    font.save(filepath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
 

I tried to merge the original Glyph and the watermark into a single layer by combining their outlines into one set of contours within the font file - It just removes the entire Glyph and watermark altogether.
